# How to plot 2 separate densities within the same graph?

Tags: r

This is the head of the data,

```
structure(list(name = c("Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Australia", 
"Bahamas", "Bangladesh"), gdp = c(4402.819, 2368.471, 9228.023, 
19930.36, 10829.18, 972.6265), mort = c(78.2, 280, 68.89999, 
8.549999, 85, 71.41), latitude = c(0.3111, 0.1367, 0.3778, 0.3, 
0.2683, 0.2667), high_mortality = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), close_equator = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The question is asking me :

> Plot 2 separate densities within the same graph for gdp when high_mortality = 1 and for gdp when high_mortality = 0. Describe whether each of the distributions are (a) skewed, (b) bimodal, and (c) whether one of the conditional densities tends to yield larger values of gdp.

How do I plot it this? This is for my class.

Comment: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(df, aes(x = gdp))+geom_density()+facet_wrap(~high_mortality)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a plot distributions of multitple variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140700/how-to-create-a-plot-distributions-of-multitple-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ggplot2` solution:

First convert 'high_mortality' to a factor.

Then call 'high_mortality' in the `colour` argument to split the data and add a legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(high_mortality = factor(high_mortality)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gdp, colour = high_mortality)) +
  geom_density(aes(gdp))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Was wondering if there is a way to use just the base R to solve this?